# Creating table with multiple check constraints on a column

Tags: mysql, check-constraints

Im trying to create a new 'machines' table with a constraint on the 'network' column; it can't be null and must be any one of three different strings. Im new to SQL and its syntax and am using mysql 5.7

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `machines`;

CREATE TABLE `machines` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `hostname` varchar(255),
    `ip_address` varchar(15),
    `network` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_network CHECK (network = 'INTERNAL' OR 'EXTERNAL' OR 'OTHER'),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );

INSERT INTO `machines`

VALUES
    (1, 'host1', '123.123.123.1', 'EXTERNAL'),
    (2, 'host2', '192.168.0.1', 'EXTERNAL' ),
    (3, 'host3', '192.168.0.2', '       ' );
```

I was hoping that whitespace wouldnt be entered into the row three but it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change column `network` to `ENUM`

```
CREATE TABLE `machines` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `hostname` varchar(255),
    `ip_address` varchar(15),
    `network` enum('INTERNAL','EXTERNAL','OTHER'),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

so insert give you a

> Data truncated for column 'network' at row 3

check the manual [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html)

Answer (score 0):

Define your constraint like this:

```
CONSTRAINT CHK_network CHECK (network IN ('INTERNAL', 'EXTERNAL', 'OTHER'))
```